# Upgrade Apache Storm from 1.2.3. to 2.2.0

Tags: java, blob, apache-storm, stream-processing

We are seeing below error when we migrate to Apache Storm 2.2.0 from 1.2.3. We do not see any permission issues as well on the file which it is unable to find. Also, the file exists but just the `/data` part is being appended to the actual file name due to which it is unable to find it. We want to know if some config decides this value.

PS: We are using Plaintext auth and do see below logs. But assuming they are not cause of concern.

`PlainSaslTransportPlugin [ERROR] SASL PLAIN client transport has been established.  This is totally insecure.  Please do not use this.`

**We think `File not found` is the issue. We want to know if any specific configuration is required.**

```
nimbus.log-2022-11-01 15:18:38.502 o.a.s.c.StormClusterStateImpl [INFO] set-path: /blobstore/all_test-1-1667296118-stormjar.jar/10.32.17.238:6627-1
nimbus.log-2022-11-01 15:18:38.603 o.a.s.d.n.Nimbus [WARN] begin blob download exception.
nimbus.log:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /grid/1/storm/blobs/967/data_all_test-1-1667296118-stormjar.jar/data (No such file or directory)
nimbus.log- at org.apache.storm.blobstore.LocalFsBlobStore.getBlob(LocalFsBlobStore.java:396) ~[storm-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
nimbus.log- at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus.beginBlobDownload(Nimbus.java:3767) [storm-server-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
nimbus.log- at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Processor$beginBlobDownload.getResult(Nimbus.java:4013) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
nimbus.log- at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Processor$beginBlobDownload.getResult(Nimbus.java:3992) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
nimbus.log- at org.apache.storm.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:38) [storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
nimbus.log- at org.apache.storm.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:38) [storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
nimbus.log- at org.apache.storm.security.auth.sasl.SaslTransportPlugin$TUGIWrapProcessor.process(SaslTransportPlugin.java:152) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
nimbus.log- at org.apache.storm.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:313) [storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
nimbus.log- at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_05]
nimbus.log- at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_05]
nimbus.log- at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_05]
nimbus.log:Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /grid/1/storm/blobs/967/data_all_test-1-1667296118-stormjar.jar/data (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: I would try to find the corresponding logs in my case in order to compare to your logs. Can you tell me, if you run in LocalCluster or in a distribtued cluster? And which logfile was that?

Comment: We figured out the issue. It was running in cluster mode but there were some config issues due to which permissions were not being granted as expected. Due to which it was unable to find the file